# Conditional Compilation Shorthand

Tags: rust, compilation, conditional-compilation

In my `.toml` file I define a feature turned off by default:

```
[features]
foo = []
```

If this feature is enabled I want to print "FOO":

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(feature = "foo")]
    println!("FOO");
}
```

I can then compile (and run) the code like this: `cargo run --features foo`

However, I'd prefer to use the shorthand that I see in the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#the-cfg-attribute). Something like this:

```
fn main() {
    #[cfg(foo)]
    println!("FOO");
}
```

However, when using the same `cargo run` command as earlier the print statement doesn't compile. What am I missing?

Comment: Well, that's just not what the syntax for querying attributes is. You could implement a proc macro so you can write `#[foo]` instead of `#[cfg(feature = "foo")]` if you really want to, but in my opinion simply using the syntax everyone else uses make the code much easier to understand.

Comment: @SvenMarnach In the link given above, what is meant in the docs when they give the example: `#[cfg(not(foo))]`. What is `foo` in this circumstance?

Comment: @HiDefender `// This function is only included when foo is not defined`. Turning on feature "foo" is adding the *value* `foo` to `feature`, making *feature* defined.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#set-configuration-options).

`#[cfg(foo)]` is a configuration option name. And can be set as so: `rustc --cfg foo main.rs`. For how to set it with cargo see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63541667/setting-arbitrary-configuration-options-using-cargo).

`#[cfg(feature = "foo")]` is a configuration option key-value pair.